# data manipulate on tree structure by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is tree structure and i want to have second tree structure by jquery.

```
<ul>
    <li data-id="1">
        <ul>
            <li data-id="2">
                <ul>
                    <li data-id="6"></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-id="3"></li>
    <li data-id="4"></li>
</ul>
```

this is destination structure that i want to have so how can i do that ?

```
<ul>
    <li data-id="1" data-path="1">
        <ul>
            <li data-id="2" data-path="1,2">
                <ul>
                    <li data-id="6" data-path="1,2,6"></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-id="3" data-path="3"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: RTFM, please. http://api.jquery.com

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL I have been read it but found it difficult to do what i have asked.

Comment: downvoted for being an extremely specific problem that will probably never help anyone in the future. we're not here to do your job for you.

Comment: jbabey - This is not a place where i can get help ? If i could not being figure out a problem so i ask it here. And i am not sure that how you think that it will not help anyone in future but how can you be sure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('li[data-id]').each(function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var path;
  self.parents('li[data-id]').andSelf().each(function() {
    if (path) {
      path = $(this).data('id') + ',' + path;
    } else {
      path = $(this).data('id');
    }
  });
  self.attr('data-path', path);
});
```

[See here for jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vrxEj/)

Comment: data-path should be traversed.